# How can I delete, break, unlink, or otherwise convert cross references to simple text in microsoft word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

Cross referencing figure and table captions is useful while editing a document but can become confused  when copying and pasting between large documents.

I need to pass my document to a colleague who will collate my document with others and has requested that I remove or delete any cross referencing so that my "correct" cross references do not interfere or get interfered with by any other cross references that may be in my colleagues master collated document.

My document will be cut and pasted into the master and no further complicated instructions after that point will be tolerated by my colleague.

Is there a simple way to convert my cross references to simple text? I am using microsoft word 2013.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I wanted to do was UNLINK the cross references.

To do this you can select the cross reference and hit ctrl-shift-F9
To do the whole document just select all with ctrl-A first

Answer (score 0):

I found the following with attribution at
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/delete-cross-reference/009d953f-de5e-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

> HansV MVP  HansV MVP replied on April 4, 2011
>
> If you want to remove it completely, select the cross reference and
>   press Delete on the keyboard.
>
> If you want to keep the text but remove the link, select the cross
>   reference and press Ctrl+Shift+F9.
>
> Kind regards, HansV www.eileenslounge.com

I had a document that I pulled from another document full of cross references and wanted to delete them all. The above pointed the way.

I used Ctrl+A then Ctrl+Shift+F9. Worked like a charm.